# Adjust android sdk with Google UAC

Tags: android, kotlin, uac, adjust-android

I have Adjust sdk added to my app, and someone asked me to track with it all the app downloads from the Google UAC campaign. How should I achive that? On their sdk git documentation there is nothing about that.

https://docs.adjust.com/en/google-api/#what-google-adwords-data-does-adjust-report

I have received a label ("Google UAC Android") and a key ("keyvalue")

```
 val adjustEvent = AdjustEvent("abc123")
 adjustEvent.addPartnerParameter("Google UAC Android", "keyvalue")       
 Adjust.trackEvent(adjustEvent)
```

I am not suer if i need also a token or i just use the `keyvalue` instead of token and not add a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this with Adjust SDK, you simply need to configure it as stated in the READEM and set up session tracking properly in you app. This will cause SDK to automatically upon your app launch tracks installs. And not really sure how Google UAC campaigns tracking works. Install tracking in SDK is essential to be set up, but attributing those installs to Google UAC campaign either goes via install referrer content (so make sure to check chapter about setting up things for install referrer API to work with your app) or this is simply automagically handled behind the scenes because Google is SAN (self attributing network) which will claim your install which was tracked by Adjust when Adjust asks Google does it belong to them.

Cheers